# grab text value using html agillity pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Please check the code bellow. I am trying to grab a html text value from this html doc. I want to grab text `Quick Kill 32 oz. Mosquito Yard Spray` and i already tried to do it using `SelectSingleNode` like bellow and this cant grab this text value. Any idea how to fix it?

```
string html = @"<div class='pod-plp__description js-podclick-analytics' data-podaction='product name'>
    <a class='' data-pos='0' data-request-type='sr' data-pod-type='pr' href='/p/AMDRO-Quick-Kill-32-oz-Mosquito-Yard-Spray-100530440/304755303'>
    <span class='pod-plp__brand-name'>AMDRO</span> 
    Quick Kill 32 oz. Mosquito Yard Spray
    </a>
</div>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();    
doc.Load(html);

string title = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='pod-plp__description js-podclick-analytics']span[@class='pod-plp__brand-name']")
    .InnerText;
```

Comment: Your xpath query looks little wrong there. You are missing '@' in front of the 'class' attributes. Furthermore you are targeting the <span> tag which will only give you 'AMDRO'. And you have a double 'class' in the 'span' selector.

Comment: How can i target after <span> tag? which will only grab that text?

Comment: Hmm wrong direction :) => what is the enclosing tag of <span>? It's the <a> tag. But its innertext will give you the additional 'Amdro' text. Try GetDirectInnerText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to targeting only `span[@class='pod-plp__brand-name']` which will return you only inside span but you need `following-sibling::text()` to grab text after your span. Please see my example code bellow. Also you can learn more from html-agility-pack official site.

```
var Content = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='pod-plp__brand-name']/following-sibling::text()[1]");

string title = titleAgain.InnerText.Trim();
```

Found solution [from here](https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/39804878/get-text-after-the-span-with-a-class-with-html-agility-pack)